# scp shell stops when permission denied

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell script that continuously put some data from one server to another. It works fine but I want to make it more secure. So at the moment if the other server denied the permission because   the password was changed the scipts freezes. Is there a possibility so if this occurs it just ignores this line and just goes on?

```
inotifywait -m /srv/watchfolderfilme -e create -e moved_to |
            while read path action file; do
...
sshpass -p "****" scp -r /srv/newtorrentfiles/* user@0.0.0.0:/srv/torrentfiles && rm -r /srv/newtorrentfiles/*
done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

scp is no the best tool to deal with your problem.

As George said, using public keys with ssh is the best way to get rid of password change.

Also you can do the trick with rsync like this :

```
rsync -ahz --remove-source-files /srv/newtorrentfiles/ user@SRVNAME:/srv/torrentfiles/
```

or

```
rsync -ahz /srv/newtorrentfiles/ user@SRVNAME:/srv/torrentfiles/ &&  rm -r /srv/newtorrentfiles/*
```

To be sure that all is done like you wanted (make this script more "secure"), you can send you an email if the script fails for one reason or another not due to lack of permission.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the answer you're looking for but why don't you use SSH keys?

Updated Script:

```
inotifywait -m /srv/watchfolderfilme -e create -e moved_to |
            while read path action file; do
...
scp -r /srv/newtorrentfiles/* b@B:/srv/torrentfiles && rm -r /srv/newtorrentfiles/*
done
```

**How to do it**

```
a@A:~> ssh-keygen -t rsa
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/a/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Created directory '/home/a/.ssh'.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /home/a/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/a/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
3e:4f:05:79:3a:9f:96:7c:3b:ad:e9:58:37:bc:37:e4 a@A
```

Now use ssh to create a directory ~/.ssh as user b on B. (The directory may already exist, which is fine):

```
a@A:~> ssh b@B mkdir -p .ssh
b@B's password:
```

Finally append a's new public key to b@B:.ssh/authorized_keys and enter b's password one last time:

```
a@A:~> cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh b@B 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
b@B's password:
```

From now on you can log into B as b from A as a without password:

```
a@A:~> ssh b@B
```

Source >> http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html